# Embed a Mobile Emulator on a Website?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, mobile-emulator

I'm basically wondering if it was possible to create a functionality similar to this site: http://www.howtogomo.com/en/#gomo-meter

I want to add some kind of feature on my website that will allow visitors to check to see how their websites looked on a mobile device like an iPhone or Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could fire up the android emulator from the android sdk , then using android debugging bridge fire up the following command

## adb shell

## am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://stackoverflow.com

then follow the following blog
http://android.amberfog.com/?p=168 , to take screen shot .

Answer (score 0):

No. It looks like this site renders the website on the server side, and then sends down an image of this to your browser.

If you are interested only in Android and iPhone (and similar smartphones with browsers based on webkit) then you could try a similar approach to http://iphonetester.com. This uses a frame embedded to simulate the size (in pixels) of an iPhone. Note, that even though these browsers may be based on webkit, it doesn't mean their implementation is the same - see http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html for variance across different webkit based browsers.

This won't work if you want to stray to other non webkit based browsers.